# Symfony2-entityManager inside an Entity

Tags: symfony

I am using **Symfony version 2.7.6**. I have created an entity named **EmployeeBasicInfo** having fields

1. firstname
2. lastname
3. identificationCode etc

I have created a callback function for validating Identification code in **EmployeeBasicInfo** entity itself which looks like

```
    /**
     * @Assert\Callback(groups={"edit_myinfo"})
     */
    public function validateIdentificationCode(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {


        if ($this->getEmployeeFirstName() == 'fakename') {

            $context->buildViolation('This name sounds totally fake!')
                ->atPath('employeeFirstName')
                ->addViolation();


        }
    }
```

**and this callback function works properly**

Actually I want such a callback functionality which checks identidfication code against database. I have added **$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();** inside the callback function and the error is like **Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDoctrine" of class "XXX\EmployeeBundle\Entity\EmployeeBasicInfo".**. Please advise me the effective way

Answer (score 3):

Do not inject the EntityManager in your Entity. One basic concept of the DataMapper-Pattern is, that your entity does not have to know about your data source and its connectors.

I'd suggest to write a custom validation constraint, in which you inject the dependencies you need.

EntityManager, Repository to query, etc. Whatever service suits you.

Have a look at [how to create custom constraint validators with dependencies](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies)

Comment: in this case I cant add callback function from controller

Comment: i have tried adding the same in the repository class. But got the same error

Comment: I have reffered this link https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/custom-validation-property-path. In it, they are connecting to the database from the entitty repository class but i still get the error

Comment: how can i use this within an entity inside a callback function??

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a service to do this

```
class EmployeeUtility($connection)
{
    public function __construct($conn) { $this->connection = $v; }

    public function validateIdentificationCode($emloyeeId, $validationCode)
    {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

In your controller, you inject the service:

```
$employeeUtility = $this->get('employee.utility');
$employeeUtility->validateIdentificationCode(1,'GF38883dkDdW3373d');
```

Alternatively, add the code in a repository class.