# Symfony2 - database checking in entity callback function

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

**I am using Symfony version 2.7.6**. I have created an entity named EmployeeBasicInfo having fields

firstname
lastname
identificationCode etc

I have created a callback function for validating Identification code in EmployeeBasicInfo entity itself which looks like

```
    /**
     * @Assert\Callback(groups={"edit_myinfo"})
     */
    public function validateIdentificationCode(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {

        if ($this->getEmployeeIdentificationCode() == 10) {

            $context->buildViolation('Identification code exists!')
                ->atPath('employeeFirstName')
                ->addViolation();


        }
    }
```

I want to redefine the same function having a database check. Issue is that i cant make queries to database within this function. I have tried with $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); and all. But failed. The same i had dome with codeigniter and yii. Please eomeone help me

This is the error i get **Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDoctrine" of class "XXX\EmployeeBundle\Entity\EmployeeBasicInfo**

Comment: To clarify, you added `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()` to `validateIdentificationCode` and it threw this exception? Your entity `EmployeeBasicInfo` is (I assume) a POPO (plain old PHP object) and as such does not inherit from any `ContainerAware` parent. You would have to inject the `EntityManager` into your entity - although I'd assume that's not best practice. Interesting question...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2-entityManager inside an Entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305856/symfony2-entitymanager-inside-an-entity)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. Entity should be as simple as possible, should have no logic. You should move your database check out of your entity to some service, inject `Doctrine` there and do your check inside service.

Error you get is just saying that you are trying to call method `getDoctrine` which doesn't exist in your entity (and that's ok, your entity should not have such method).

Comment: i already have a service app.util with a function in it..i am calling that from this entity like $this->get('app.util')->test(). for the same im also getting some error

Comment: do you inject your service into entity? If no, your entity know nothing about your service or doctrine, that's why you get an error. You should not this function in entity but in service

Comment: is their any reference link for creating a service, configuring it for dorctrine and injecting in entity???

Comment: i am new to symfony.. please help me...its taking lots of my time

Comment: no, because you should not inject anything into entity

Comment: ok let me ask you this, then how can i do database related callback validations for an entity?

Comment: create your own validator http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies